# Remove widgets on mobile front page without affecting desktop

Tags: widgets, mobile

I customized my desktop page with widgets so that the articles are arranged into different aesthetically pleasing sections... but on my mobile page, I'd like all the articles to just show up by order of last published without being arranged into sections.

Is it possible to not have the widgets on the mobile page separately... while still having widgets on desktop?

I saw a lot of answers that mentioned CSS media queries, but it looks like that's just adjusting header/stylistic things. I also saw a thing about redirecting, but I would prefer for the mobile to have the same link as the desktop. Is this possible?

Thank you so much.

Edit: I would also like to be able to add back the function of having the latest posts on mobile, as I had to remove it from desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is enough for your needs to use the native (mobile) devices check [wp_is_mobile()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_mobile/).